# ORACLE TEXT SEARCH

Tags: oracle, oracle-text

I want to be able to match (as close as possible) two fields of text. Any ideas on how to do this in Oracle. I have looked into using Context in Oracle Text, but I have no idea on how to parse one of the fields to input to contain clause in the select.

Example: Search 'This is Red Car' would return 'Red Car belongs to Stephen' based on 'red car'in both values.

Comment: There's a difference between finding all the text which contains a specific string (such as 'red car') and scoring the *similarity* of strings by scoring their whole content. Text is good for the first task not so much for the second. Actually the two strings you give aren't very similar. They have two identical tokens - 'red' and 'car' - but there's no other matching token.

Answer (score 1):

I think the term you're looking for is **string similarity**. There are [a LOT of different algorithms](https://www.joyofdata.de/blog/comparison-of-string-distance-algorithms/) that you can choose from in trying to figure out how similar two strings are.

But if you want a quick and easy solution, take a look at [UTL_MATCH](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_match.htm#ARPLS72002). It can give you a simple numeric score from 0-100 for determining how similar two strings are. It only has 2 algorithms to choose from. For your two example strings:

`utl_match.edit_distance_similarity('This is Red Car', 'Red Car belongs to Stephen')` gives a score of 12 (from 0-100) using the basic edit / Levenshtein distance.

`utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity('This is Red Car', 'Red Car belongs to Stephen')` gives a score of 51 (also 0-100). So I'm guessing you might want to use this one for your purpose. But feel free to try them both out on your real data, or try writing your own code based on a different well-known algorithm (I saw someone use the Sørensen–Dice coefficient, for example).